# table set td width the same for all cells in row

Tags: html, css

I have a table where i want every cell in the header row have the same width. This is my current code:

```css
table {width:100%}
table td{border: 1px solid}
.header td{ }
```

```html
<html>

 <table>
  <tr class="header"><td colspan="2">header </td><td> header</td></tr>
  <tr><td> content </td><td> content </td><td> content </td></tr>
 </table>
</html>
```

Basically, i could get the result with this.

```css
 
table td{border: 1px solid}
.header td{ width: 100px}
```

```html
<html>

 <table>
  <tr class="header"><td colspan="2">header </td><td> header</td></tr>
  <tr><td> content </td><td> content </td><td> content </td></tr>
 </table>
</html>
```

However, i want the following things:

- The table has to support a variable (%) width.
- The css has to work with a variable number of columns (so setting width to 50% would not work)
- If possible, i am looking for a css only solution (no javascript)

Comment: `The css has to work with a variable number of rows` do you mean columns?

Comment: How you want exactly.. Pl explain clearly or better show as image of how you want?

Comment: have you try colspan?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @atifAzad If i set colspan on both cells to two, it does not make any difference.

Comment: @Paulie_D I want each cell in the header row to have the same width.

Comment: @Etash The second snippets shows exactly what i want, except that is uses fixed width and i want it to work with table width: ... %

Comment: Do you mean like this - http://jsfiddle.net/f9xd09qw/1/

Comment: @AtifAzad I am already using colspan. Can you tell me how i should change it to achieve my result?

Comment: @Paulie_D Like that, but then let both the header columns have the same width.

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/979yek3y/

Comment: Then no...you are supposed to have the same number of header columns as row columns **unless** you account for any difference by using `colspan`...A js solution would be required.

Comment: Do you want same width for heading / for td? like this http://jsfiddle.net/ws3Lm1ku/4/ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may jut look for `table-layout:fixed;` wich sprays evenly cols when no width are specified or applyes width specified without expanding :

```css
table {width:100%; table-layout:fixed;}
table td{border: 1px solid}
.header td{ }
```

```html
<html>

 <table>
  <tr class="header"><td colspan="2">header </td><td> header</td></tr>
  <tr><td> content </td><td> content </td><td> content </td></tr>
 </table>
</html>
```

Mind the the use of `th` and/or `theader` to filter tags/content

```css
table td, th{
  border: 1px solid;
  table-layout:fixed;/* sprays evenly col width if no width set */
}
.header td{ 
  width:100px; /* table-layout if fixed will follow this value */
}
```

```html
<html>

 <table>
  <tr class="header"><th colspan="2">header header header </th><th> header</th></tr>
  <tr><td> content </td><td> content </td><td> content  content  content </td></tr>
 </table>
</html>
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. The only thing that is missing is setting all cells in the last column to colspan="2", if i do that it does exactly what i want.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question it can be solved using js like this:

```
var heads = $('table thead tr th');
var len = heads.length;
$.each(heads, function(i, e){
  $(e).width(100.0/len + '%');
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/311k5c6g/

I have not been able to find a pure css solution.

Comment: I am still looking for a css only solution. However, if that is not possible, this also works great.

Comment: Good luck in your search. I think you might take a look on how bootstrap handles justified button groups. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups